# SearchKit - can I return the first four characters of a string?

Tags: drupal-views, searchkit

I would like to run a report of UK postcodes with aggregation. The first four characters of the postcode give an area of perhaps a few square miles, the last three characters are specific to a street so not very helpful.

Is it possible to do this in SearchKit by rewriting the text or using the field transformation to do this? I did wonder about using the Data Segmentation but we can have up to 70 different variations (and this isn't always predictable) so this would have to be perhaps 40-50 of the most common ones and then 'Other' as a catch all. Setting up the criteria for 'Other' could also be problematic if we have to say != one of 40 other defined patterns.

We currently use Views with some simple raw SQL :

> Left(civicrm_address.postal_code,4)

...but a colleague has spotted that the numbers don't add up properly. I can try to troubleshoot that but I'd rather recreate it in SearchKit if it's possible.

*(If you're interested, the issue in Views is that the subtotal appears to be correct and matches a search of contacts in the main database, but if I copy and paste the list into Excel and run a SUM formula, it's about 5% out).*

Answer (score 4):

I've put up a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26549) to make `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `SUBSTRING()` available.  If you don't want to wait for the release with these, just put a copy of those files into the right place.

That will let you show the truncated string in SearchKit but you can't add the `Group By` directly although SearchKit *does* understand it.  So ...

1. Set up the rest of your search and add a Group By using the relevant `postal_code` (ignore the truncation part for now)
2. Save your search, go to the main search listing and click `Export`.
3. Use the `Copy to clipboard` button
4. Close the pop-up, and click `Import` on the Saved Searches listing.
5. In the pop-up, paste what you just exported.
6. Go the `groupBy` section and change `address_primary.postal_code` to `LEFT(address_primary.postal_code, 4)`

[image]

7. Finish with `Import`
8. Now open the search.  You should see the grouping correctly displayed eg:

[image]

... and the results should be grouped as you want. :-)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the instructions. Only two slight comments - when I imported it, it overwrote the one that used to export/copied from and I wasn't expecting that, although it makes perfect sense. I'm just stating it here in case anyone is following this and wants to keep a separate copy of before and after. Secondly, the agreggation is working but the label in my Postcode column still shows full postcodes - should I be able to use LEFT in the field transformation (it's not listed)?

Comment: 1) Good catch about overwriting  2) yes, the `LEFT` in the Group By is separate from any displayed columns, so if you want to display the postcode, also add a `LEFT` to it, but you can do that in the field transformation part of the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Civi provides a smarty modifier that's the same as php substr, so if you add a search display to your searchkit you can check the box for rewrite on the field and use that modifier, like:

`{'[postal_code]'|substring:0:4}`

The single quotes are important.

The exact token depends your query. It might be something like `[Address.postal_code]`. You can use the `</>` dropdown to insert it.

P.S. I am seeing some strangeness though. It works for `1:4`, but not `0:4`. Odd.

Comment: This was my first thought too, but I think the asker is trying to aggregate by the first four digits, which would have to happen in the search itself, I think, rather than the display.

Comment: Ok if that's the case then perhaps core would accept adding LEFT as an option: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/51ec12f5c890cce5fecf393d60d5a3921aa9eff6/Civi/Api4/Query. It seems generally useful.

Comment: Agreed, seems like a good addition to me.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. Yes, it would need to be in the search so it would be great if that could be added as an option!

Comment: There's a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26549) up to add it but now that I'm looking at it, for this specific use case I'm not sure it will help. I don't see where you can group-by on a transformed field in searchkit.